# json serialization with inheritance in dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I am using json annotation package to generate the json serialization boilerplate code. I have Base class

```
@JsonSerializable()
class UIWidget {
  double? size = 50;
  List<UIWidget> children = List.empty(growable: true);
  factory UIWidget.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UIWidgetFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UIWidgetToJson(this);
}
```

I have several subclasses and one such is given below.

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class UIGridView extends UIWidget {
  int scrollDirection = Axis.vertical.index;
  String _showAxis = "Vertical";
  int crossAxisCount = 3;
  double mainAxisSpacing = 0.0;
  double crossAxisSpacing = 0.0;
  double childAspectRatio = 1.0;
  factory UIGridView.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UIGridViewFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UIGridViewToJson(this);

}
```

If you notice, the UIWidget class has children property, which can contain any of the sub classes. The problem arise when I tried to generate the code. The fromJson method is generated as follows

```
..children = (json['children'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => UIWidget.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList();
```

However, I needed to call the subclass fromjson and create instance of subclass. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Where's your `super()` constructor? If you're extending `UIWidget`, you need to pass your params from the extending class to the parent class, and codegen will work as expected.

```dart
// Base class
@JsonSerializable()
class ParentClass {
  final String? someString;

  const ParentClass({
    this.someString,
  });

  factory ParentClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ParentClassFromJson(json);

  Map<String, String> toJson() => Map.from(_$ParentClassToJson(this));
}

// Child class extending base
@JsonSerializable()
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  final List<int> exampleList;

  const ChildClass({
    required this.exampleList,
    String? someString,
  }) : super(someString: someString);

  factory ChildClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ChildClassFromJson(json);

  Map<String, String> toJson() =>
      Map.from(_$ChildClassToJson(this));
}
```

Comment: Yes, we are able achieve this. But the problem starts after this. In your example, instead of List<int> exampleList, if you change to List<ParentClass> exampleList and assign add ChildClass instance to the list, the code gen generates code to call ParentClass.fromJson where the information of ChildClass is getting lost.